# Number I've participated in Tags hard to read

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

This is on both Meta and AskDifferent

[image]

Maybe Mr. CSS can search for the same color being used at multiple places if it occurs more than once :)

**EDIT:** This class is missing as it is available [here](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/tags)

```
    #tags_list .item-multiplier {
color: #666;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have pushed a darkened text to dev. The change will be on live after our next production build.